# How to set custom XMPP Message.Type string in Smack?

Tags: xmpp, smack

```
MultiUserChatManager mucManager = MultiUserChatManager.getInstanceFor(conn);
MultiUserChat muc = mucManager.getMultiUserChat("meet_alice@conference.buddyme.com");

newMsg = muc.createMessage();
newMsg.setBody(strMsg);
newMsg.setType(Message.Type.groupchat);
```

My requirement is to pass custom message type in

```
newMsg.setType(Message.Type.groupchat);
```

For example instead of passing `"Message.Type.groupchat"` I want to pass `"Message.Type.image"` or some string "image" which is not present in type by default.

Answer (score 3):

Setting a different message type then the defined ones in the XMPP RFC is not allowed as it would produce invalid message stanzas. Use a custom extension element added to the message stanza instead.

Instead of

```
<message type='my-custom-message-type-news' …>
  <body>
    This is a message with a custom message type 'news'.
    Do not do this!
  </body>
</message>
```

do

```
<message …>
  <body>
    This is a message with additional metadata found in a custom
    extension element. In this example the message is tagged as 'news'.
    That is how you extend XMPP and tag messages.
  </body>
  <my-custom-extension-element xmlns='https://my.company.com' type='news'>
    <more-metadata-if-you-want date='2018-04-03'/>
  </my-custom-extension-element>
</message>
```

Comment: i am new to ejabberd, so not much familiar with custom extensions. It will be really helpful if you can post some example code for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom type by editing **Message** class in (**org.jivesoftware.smack.packet**)

in Enum defined your custom type

```
 public enum Type {

    /* CUSTOM TYPE */
    image

    /**
     * (Default) a normal text message used in email like interface.
     */
    normal,

    /**
     * Typically short text message used in line-by-line chat interfaces.
     */
    chat,

    /**
     * Chat message sent to a groupchat server for group chats.
     */
    groupchat,

    /**
     * Text message to be displayed in scrolling marquee displays.
     */
    headline,

    /**
     * indicates a messaging error.
     */
    error;

    /**
     * Converts a String into the corresponding types. Valid String values that can be converted
     * to types are: "normal", "chat", "groupchat", "headline" and "error".
     * 
     * @param string the String value to covert.
     * @return the corresponding Type.
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException when not able to parse the string parameter
     * @throws NullPointerException if the string is null
     */
    public static Type fromString(String string) {
        return Type.valueOf(string.toLowerCase(Locale.US));
    }

}
```

For **Sending Messages**, You can simply set your custom type (image) as follows :

```
Message message = new Message();
message.setType(Message.Type.image);
message.setStanzaId("123");
message.setTo(number);
try {
   connection.sendStanza(message);
} catch (NotConnectedException e) {
}
```

and For **Receiving Message** of custom type use following code

```
StanzaTypeFilter message_filter = new StanzaTypeFilter(Message.class);
connection.addSyncStanzaListener(new StanzaListener() {
    @Override
    public void processPacket(Stanza packet) throws NotConnectedException {
       Message message = (Message)packet;
       if(message.getType() == Message.Type.image) {
          //your code
       }
    }    
}, message_filter);
```

**________________________________________________________________**

**EDIT : YOU NEED TO ADD THE SOURCE CODE FILES INTO YOUR PROJECT (DON'T NEED TO RECOMPILE THE JAR FILE)**

**________________________________________________________________**

I am using Smack 4.1.2 in my project. You can download it from the link below
https://www.igniterealtime.org/downloads/download-landing.jsp?file=smack/smack_4_1_2.zip

Unzip it, In libs folder **each modules** have 3 jar file
for example

1. **smack-android-4.1.2.jar**
2. **smack-android-4.1.2-javadoc.jar**
3. **smack-android-4.1.2-sources.jar**

All you need is simple jar files, Add the required jar files in your project lib folder. for example, I am using following jars, below is my **app.gradle**

```
compile files('libs/smack-core-4.1.2-sources.jar')
compile files('libs/smack-android-4.1.2.jar')
compile files('libs/smack-extensions-4.1.2.jar')
compile files('libs/smack-im-4.1.2.jar')
compile files('libs/smack-sasl-provided-4.1.2.jar')
compile files('libs/smack-tcp-4.1.2.jar')
```

Now, for customizing Smack (that is adding custom type), you need to add the code into your project

Unzip **smack-core-4.1.2-*sources*.jar** and add the java code files into your project and now you can edit the **Message.java**

Comment: While modifying the libraries code sure would work, **you really shouldn't do it** (unless you don't want to use XMPP any more).

Comment: WhatsApp uses a customized version of the open standard Extensible Messaging and Presence Protocol (XMPP). [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WhatsApp),
 so there is no harm customizing the XMPP a/c to the needs

Comment: As I said, if you don't care about no longer talking XMPP you can do that.

Comment: @shanrais actually I've edit the message class as you said but I don't know how to recompile the source code and generate the jar file. Can you tell me how did you do that?

Comment: i have edited my answer, please check. hope it helps.